# How do I add elements of a "zipped" list

Tags: list, zip, addition

I have a list and I want to add each of the pairs in the list
For example:
mylist = [(0,5), (4,5), (2,3)]
I want to get
newlist = [5, 9, 5]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever language this is you could use a map.  In python it would look like:

```
map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], my_list)
```

Or even simpler:

```
map(sum, my_list)
```

Both returning:

```
[5, 9, 5]
```